# How to filter a specific value within a dictionary?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have this dictionary:

```
{
    "name": "Jorje",
    "surname": "Costali",
    "extra_information": {
        "real_name": "mamino",
        "fake_name": "bambino",
        "age": "43",
        "gang": "gang34"
    }
}
```

How can I query to get all entries that have `"extra_information.gang":"gang34"` ? I would like to know how to filter after exact term or having a match.

I have tried:

```
{
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "extra_information.gang": [
                            "gang34"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

but it does not return any entries.

I have tried:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "extra_information.gang" : "gang34"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and works, but I want to make it into a filter, not a simple match query.

Comment: What Elasticsearch version are you using and what is the mapping of the `gang` field?

Comment: If your mapping is correct then the first query should have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use `.keyword`? like:

```
"terms": {
    "extra_information.gang.keyword": [
        "gang34"
    ]
}
```

I tried what you wrote on my nested dictionary document, it works like this to me.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The documentation is not so intuitive for my kind of programming mentality :) But I still don't understand why it works

Comment: Text fields in elastic search can be mapped as ‘text’ or ‘keyword’, the difference between them is: ‘keyword’ means that you search for the entire text, but ‘text’ means that you search for a part of it, in your case you had to tell it to search for ‘gang’ field that its entire value is ‘gang34’.